# Is a date within some of periods

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following table of projects with their activity periods (periods are defined with FROM and TO dates):

```
ID | ProjID | ActiveFrom | ActiveTo
===+========+============+============
 1 |     20 | 2018-01-01 | 2018-01-20
 2 |     20 | 2018-02-05 | 2018-02-12
 3 |     20 | 2018-02-20 | 2018-02-27
 4 |     30 | 2018-01-15 | 2018-02-15
```

Of course, a project can have an arbitrary number of activity periods.

I need a SQL query (function) which will return true/false if a given project was active on some given date (is given date within some of project's activity periods).

Comment: Great! So have you [*tried anything*](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592) so far?

Comment: Hint:  `WHERE` and some date comparisons.

Comment: Yes I tried something but I have the problem with arbitrary number of periods. If number of periods is known, then it's peace of cake, but how to check within unknown number of periods.

Comment: Hint: `SELECT
 CASE COUNT(*) WHEN > 0 THEN TRUE ELSE FALSE
FROM
  project
WHERE
  '2018-11-21' BETWEEN(ActiveFrom, ActiveTo)`

Comment: Thanks @AntonyGibbs that's good hint:
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM projects WHERE projId=20 AND '2018-01-21' BETWEEN ActiveFrom AND ActiveTo

Comment: Thanks... but I see I forgot to put `GROUP BY ProjectId` at the end - it is required to be able to use `COUNT()`

Comment: @AntonyGibbs GROUP BY is not need, I filtered Project with WHERE ProjID=20 and use COUNT(*) over the whole resultset (GROUP BY is not needed then)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This function should do what you want. It relies on MySQL treating boolean results as either 1 or 0 in a numeric context, thus the `MAX` call effectively becomes an `OR` of all the conditions.

```
CREATE FUNCTION check_activity(project_id INT, check_date DATE)
RETURNS BOOLEAN
DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN
  RETURN (SELECT MAX(check_date BETWEEN ActiveFrom AND ActiveTo) FROM projects WHERE ProjId = project_id);
END
SELECT check_activity(20, '2018-01-10'), check_activity(20, '2018-02-01')
```

Output

```
check_activity(20, '2018-01-10')    check_activity(20, '2018-02-01')
1                                   0
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=709ff9a7aa0679a5e8057fe6a1d9427b)

Comment: That's it, I'm not used to using BETWEEN as logic test in SELECT (I always used it in WHERE clause). Guys negatively marked my question although it's not as simple as it looks like.

Comment: @sbrbot agreed, the unknown number of periods does make it more complicated. The fact that MySQL treats booleans as integers makes it possible to come up with a relatively easier solution rather than having to loop through all the periods. Note that since it is a one-liner in the end you probably don't need to enclose it in a function.

Comment: Exactly, here @Nick used MAX to return 1 if a requested date is at least within one period (if there's no overlapping than only one 1 exists, but non-overlapping periods were not specified). Also I wanted to avoid looping through periods within a function and that's why I changed that need query (then function). However, I think guys underestimated the question.